# Cassandra CQL Java driver returns a empty list instead of null

Tags: java, cassandra, cql3

I have a custom type defined like the follow:

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS typetest (
  id text,
  name text,
  parents list<text>
);
```

And a table that uses this custom type together with another list of texts:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS randomTable (
    id text,
    categories frozen<list<word>>,
    kitProducts list<text>,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH compaction = {'unchecked_tombstone_compaction': 'true', 'tombstone_threshold': '0.1', 'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_kb': '64', 'sstable_compression': 'DeflateCompressor'};
```

And after I insert a value into it, with kitProducts = null and parents = null:

```
insert into randomTable (id, categories) values ('id1',[{id: 'hey', name: 'how', parents: null }]);
```

And when I try to read this data using the Java library (MappingManager - http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/mapping/MappingManager.html) the **categories parent** attribute is an empty list and the **kitProducts** attribute is null. I read somewhere that the CQL driver transforms a list with null value into a empty list for performance porpouses, but in this case is transforming just for one case and I am not finding why.
Is it happening because its a custom type?
I dont mind if returns a empty list or a null, I just need it to be the same in all cases.

Appreciate any help,

Regards.

PS: I am using datastax.driver.core version 3.1